# Why is my textarea higher up than its neighbor?

Tags: html, css

Picture:

[image]

```css
.left {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
textarea {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <span class='left'>
        <span>one</span>
        <span>two</span>
     </span>
     <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjwzqY?editors=110)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why is my textarea higher up than its neighbor?

It's not.

Let me explain.

***First, a bit of background:***

Your `span` and `textarea` elements are (by default) [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente).

Browsers normally provide a little bit of whitespace underneath inline elements for **descenders**.

To understand descenders...

> Look at this line of text. Notice there are no letters that breach the baseline.

Now look at the following sentence:

> By just crossing the bridge he probably got away.

Note the letters "y", "j", "p" and "g". These letters breach the [baseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)) and are known in typography as "[descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender)".

[[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Typographic_descenders.png)</sup>

The gap you're seeing is not margin or padding, but simply the browser providing room to accommodate these lowercase letters. In short, this is called [baseline alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

> [***baseline***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))
>
> The line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend.
>
> [[image]
>
> <sup>Source: [Wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography))</sup>

So why, somebody might ask, does the browser provide this space for `textarea`, `img`, `input` and other inline elements, that don't need space for descenders?

Because the browser adjusts for the possibility that you may have text before or after one of those elements on the same line.

***Now, to your image and code...***

On first glance it clearly appears that the `textarea` is higher up than the `span` element. But if you take a closer look...

[image]

...you'll see they are perfectly aligned. Both `span` and `textarea` are providing space for descenders.

[image]

The borders you've added contribute to the appearance of misalignment because the `textarea` border wraps a clearly delineated box while *excluding descender space*, but the `span` border wraps the text *and the descender space*. If you remove the red border the misalignment is less pronounced.

In terms of a solution, here are two options:

1. Add `vertical-align: bottom` to the `textarea` rule, OR
2. Add `display: block` to the `textarea` rule.

Comment: OMG best answer i've read yet... However here is a question.. if you have a div.. and the text is "New"... no descenders... but, you can clearly see a difference in space for the descenders... is there a way to sort of "shrink-wrap" the text. By the way this is a div with just text...not an inner span or anything.

Comment: @carinlynchin, try using the `line-height` property... https://stackoverflow.com/q/45112764/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I tried that but there is still a small difference on the bottom space.

Comment: @carinlynchin, post a new question with all the details.

Comment: @Michael_B  Here you can see a pic. http://gravityvisuals.com/images/test.png.   Notice the spacing is slightly bigger on the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Adam,

If you add the following to your existing css, you should get your desired results.

```
.left{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

textarea{
    margin:0px;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

You can see a working example at the following url: https://jsfiddle.net/YOOOEE/z8pwpms6/

Comment: 1) That works, but the only necessary change is `textarea { vertical-align: text-bottom; }`. The rest is extraneous. In particular, the default margin for the `textarea` is `0px`. 2) I think a complete answer would address the "why", not just the "fix". Ie. what user1843159 is saying in the comments about baseline.

Comment: @AdamZerner it seems to me that the `margin: 0` is needed on Firefox in order to align both borders, but not in Chrome.

Comment: @AdamZerner Every browser has own default styles for elements and these styles are not always identical for the different HTML elements. Like user "Zimmi" said you might need some styles for specific browsers only. That is the reason why it is also recommended to use something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to have the same base-style in most browsers...

Answer (score 0):

If you have two span elements, the high will be the same.  Spans have display:inline; by default.

```
<span class="left">
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
  </span>
<span class="right">
    <span>one</span>
    <span>two</span>
 </span>
```

All browsers have defaults styles for textareas:

```
textarea {
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-image-source: initial;
    border-image-slice: initial;
    border-image-width: initial;
    border-image-outset: initial;
    border-image-repeat: initial;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    flex-direction: column;
    resize: auto;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
    margin: 0em;
    font: 13.3333px Arial;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
}
```

My solution:

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}
```