# Span next to img inside div overflows div border

Tags: html, css

So I have some generated html that I am attempting to style. The html seems fairly normal to me, and the css I am trying to apply is minimal, but it is acting in a way that I would not expect.

The html places a `div` with an anchor tag, containing both an `img` and some text inside the `div`, wrapped (for some reason) in a `span`.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 40px;
}


.title img {
    height: 100%    
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="title ">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Commons_app_72_72px.png">   
            <span>Sample Text</span>
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the link text is outside the border of the `div`.

If I get rid of the image, the text is aligned properly, but adding the `img` seems to stretch the containing span outside the borders of the `div` its supposedly contained in, despite the fact that the `img` is not any bigger than the `div` and does not stretch to the new size of the `span`. It almost looks like the `img` and `span` inside the anchor are not aligned and the `span` is stretching to allow them to be weirdly offset.

The weird nesting of the `div` and `span` with class `title` is not something I have control over, so if the solution to my problem requires changing that, please explain why.

How do I get rid of this weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image, which is an inline element by default, is provided space underneath for  [**descenders**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276).

One way to resolve the issue is with [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

So instead of:

```
.title img {
    height: 100%;    
}
```

Try:

```
.title img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;   
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/arqkm2ty/)

Learn more about descenders here:

- [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)
- [Why is my textarea higher up than it's neighbor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32442522/3597276)

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Now I actually understand how to avoid this sort of thing in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just add **vertical-align: middle** for image:

```
.title img {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you want to align text by top boundary than set vertical-align to top.

Images are inline element. By default strings are aligned to the baseline. Since image larger than text line height, text is aligned to the lower boundary.