# How to remove few pixels of whitespace underneath textarea?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I have a wrapper for a textarea, the textarea's height does not match the textarea's height. There's a few pixels of margin at the bottom. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

E.g.:

```
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

The div will be a few pixels taller than the textarea.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0dgjqp3b/

I don't want to explicitly set the height of the parent. The parent should wrap around the textarea even if the textarea resizes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my textarea higher up than it's neighbor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414736/why-is-my-textarea-higher-up-than-its-neighbor)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `textarea` element's `display` is `inline-block` [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366401/css-inline-block-elements-not-lining-up-properly/19366432#19366432). As a result, its `vertical-align` property is set to `baseline` (which is why it isn't aligned as you would expect). The reason there is [reserved space at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/why-an-image-inside-a-div-has-an-extra-space-below-the-image/5804278#5804278) is for letters such as 'y' or 'j', which hang below adjacent letters/elements.

To resolve this, you can either change the `vertical-align` property value to something like `top`, or you could change the `display` of the `textarea` to `block`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/m5q4njf1/)

```
textarea {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/273v4nnc/)

```
textarea {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block` to the `textarea` element.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dgjqp3b/)

Comment: @Linksku What is your browser version?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:block;` to the `textarea`

```js
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer uses much of the code in the previous answers but with one new addition.

```css
div{border:1px solid red;display:table;vertical-align:middle;}
textarea{margin:0;padding:0;vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div>
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Let me know if there is anything else I can do.