# Vertical alignment of inline-grid elements

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't understand the logic of vertical alignment of `inline-grid` elements.

The 2nd example works fine (see the code), but the 1st is not. Why? And how I could fix it, as shown below in screenshot?

[image]

> Also note.
>
> Instead of using `display: inline-grid`, we can use `display: inline-flex` + `flex-direction: column` with the same result.
>
> Thus, if the task could not be achieved with `inline-grid`, probably it could be solved using `inline-flex`.

[For ones, who prefer jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5roxxy02/)

```css
body {
 width: 500px;
}

.inline-grid {
 display: inline-grid;
 width: 49%;
}

div {
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>not ok</h3>

<div class="inline-grid">
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-grid">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<hr>

<h3>ok</h3>

<div class="inline-grid">
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
<div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="inline-grid">
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`vertical-align`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align?v=example) property applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. The default value is `baseline`. Because you're using `display: inline-grid`, this rule is factoring into your code.

Override the default with `vertical-align: bottom`.

```
.inline-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 49%;
  vertical-align: bottom; /* new */
}
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5roxxy02/1/)

More info:

- [Why is there a vertical scroll bar if parent and child have the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36974514/3597276)
- [Why is my textarea higher up than its neighbor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414736/3597276)
- [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444891/3597276)

---

**UPDATE** (based on comments)

> The only problem, is that `vertical-align: bottom` (as well as other
>   values of vertical align) also affects second example. What I actually
>   want is to align items according to the middle red line. (As shown in
>   my screenshot). I don't know, maybe it just impossible?

Yes, it's possible. Here's a revised Grid solution:

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5roxxy02/3/)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

div > div { border: 1px solid red; }
img       { vertical-align: bottom; }
body      { width: 500px; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div style="align-self: end;"><code>align-self: end</code> || Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
  <div style="align-self: start"><code>align-self: start</code></div>
  <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/joY41yV.png"></div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
```

*Note: Consider removing the div wrappers around the images. They may not be necessary. I only left them in my answer because they are needed for properly rendering the (demo?) borders. Once you remove those wrappers, you can also get rid of the `vertical-align` rule in the CSS.*

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `vertical-align: bottom;`

```
body {
    width: 500px;
}

.inline-grid {
    display: inline-grid;
    width: 49%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

div {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here the JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/4sh9oo5k/

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted for justice, but I also should note that this answer haven't any differences from Michael's.