# CSS reserves an unknown space in box model

Tags: html, css, layout

I created a `<div>` with some text. I set the width and padding of the `<div>` and the font-size of the text inside it. Below is a snippet summarizing the conflict:

```css
.container {
  width:     300px;
  padding:   10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Hello
</div>
```

According to the code, the total height (which is the offsetHeight in javascript) is 36. However, when I look at the layout in Chrome dev tools, the height reads 38. So, where did those 2px come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra height is caused by the `line-height` property.

The initial value of `line-height` is `normal`.

This, [according to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height), tells browsers to set the value up to 1.2. This gives the text a bit of vertical padding inside the line box.

To resolve the issue, just add `line-height: 1` to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers implement a default line height to text. So in this case there is 1 pixel below and above the text. You can change this by setting `line-height: 16px;`