# html - flush 2 cells completely

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to figure out why the red background color is still showing?  I'd like to make the two cells flush together so no red is displayed.

see jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7c73417b/1/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="imageThumbN">
            <a href=""}">
            <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/5y5wc8jqp/test1.png" width="130" height="130" border="0"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="imageLink">
            <a href="">ImagesS</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mystery white space underneath image tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444891/mystery-white-space-underneath-image-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS: `img { vertical-align: bottom; }`

or

apply `font-size: 0` to `td.imageThumbN`

or

apply `display: block` to `td.imageThumbN`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7c73417b/3/)

For an explanation, see my answer here:  [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: inline-block` to your image.