# How to remove spacing around <img> in CSS?

Tags: css, image, spacing

I have this weird spacing on the bottom and right of an image and I want to remove it. I have set the padding and margin to 0px but it still shows. This is annoying as I want the images to neatly fit into the outer box with zero spacing for a pixel perfect appearance.

```css
img.news_title_icon {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;
}
body {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px; /* for testing */
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  background-color: #001133;
  color: white;
}
div.news_title_container {    
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
.light_container, .dark_container {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.57);
  border: 1px solid #005eff;  
}
.light_container {
  background-color: rgba(0, 34, 102, 0.8); 
}
```

```html
<div class="news_title_container light_container">
  <img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image">
  <img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image">
  <img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image">
</div>
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: [Mystery white space underneath image tag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline blocks have this issue. For more details [read this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)
There are several ways

1. using float.
2. Using flexbox.
3. Removing white spaces between tags in html.
4. Negative margins
5. .....

for example there is not your issue.

```
<div class="news_title_container light_container">
  <img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image"><img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image"><img class="news_title_icon" alt="an image">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh right, that did fix it but it'll make coding a real pain to have to fit it on one line. I'll look into the flexbox idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:left` for image.

```
img.news_title_icon {
    float: left;   //added this
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

Updated based on OP comment
use this

```
div.news_title_container {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 0; //added this
}
```

Comment: The only problem with that is then the background panel does not contain the images. The images float outside of it.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I suppose actually I could just make the background panel 80px in height. It seems a little messy in cases where I want to put in another image but that'll have to do. Thanks.