# Image resizes to max-height but page overflows

Tags: html, css, image, height, overflow

I have a `img` that resizes to the footer height (10vh) with `max-height: 100%`. In Dev tools the size of each element seems to be OK but somehow the page is overflowing and I can`t figure out where the extra px height comes from.
Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.header {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: green;
}
.footer {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="content">

</div>
<div class="footer">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/19/18/00/city-1150026_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Why does this happen and how can I avoid it?

UPDATE: I had no idea that the default `display: inline` of `<img>` was causing this. Now that I know it is much easier to find other answers to my question (I just didn`t know what to search for). For those who may be searching for this issue and find my question here is a complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/6453726

SOLUTION: Add `vertical-align: top` to the `<img>`.

Comment: Because your image is an inline element, [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Comment: Thank you. I woudn't had understood what was happening if I just added display: block to the img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block;` to your `img` selector

```
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Adding display block to the img solved the overflow problem but added another. If I put the <img> inside <a> them the link will fill the whole width cause that is the block behavior. Now that I know that the display: inline was causing this issue I found some other solutions. Adding vertical-align: top to <img> worked better for me. Thank you though.