# HTML Table Spacing Between Rows

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for a fairly simple table I made. The problem is there is extra white spacing around the bottom of the first and second row of the table. Why is that. I've tried multiple solutions and nothing has worked.

```css
body, html { 
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #a00000;
    margin: 0; /* remove default margins added by browsers */
}
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   height: 100%;
}
table {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
}
img {
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 120px;
    border: solid 5px #a00000;
    background-color: #a00000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Bobcat Menu</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <table align="center" cellspacing="0" border-spacing="0">
<tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="mobincube://action/section/DropDay">
                        <img src="
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/D.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="mobincube://action/section/Schedule">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/S.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>      
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="mobincube://action/section/Calculators">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/C.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="mobincube://action/section/News">
                        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/N.png" />
                    </a>
                </td>      
            </tr>       
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. CSS is two decades old now.

Comment: @Quentin You say that like OP's not using CSS to style the table.

Comment: @JonUleis — I say that like they *are* using tables for layout.

Comment: The extra space is a feature of inline-level elements (such as `img`), and is designed to accommodate the *descenders* in typography: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: block;` to your `<img>` elements to ensure there's no additional spacing around them in each `<td>`. This fixes the background bleeding through.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #a00000;
  margin: 0;
  /* remove default margins added by browsers */
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
table {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 120px;
  max-height: 120px;
  border: solid 5px #a00000;
  background-color: #a00000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bobcat Menu</title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table align="center" cellspacing="0" border-spacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="mobincube://action/section/DropDay">
            <img src="
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/D.png" />
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="mobincube://action/section/Schedule">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/S.png" />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="mobincube://action/section/Calculators">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/C.png" />
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="mobincube://action/section/News">
            <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/837604/N.png" />
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```