# Nested flex box with image has extra height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a navigation bar for a page using only HTML and CSS.  It should look like this, with the logo setting the height of the containing `div`, then with the text vertically centered in other `div`s next to it.

What it should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

I've tried to do this by setting up some nested flex boxes.  The idea is that:

- The container (`nav-holder`) stretches to fit the tallest content
- The second container (`nav-item`) should all be as tall as its parent
- The third container (`nav-cont`) should be as tall as its own content, and should be vertically centered inside `nav-item`

Instead, I'm ending up with an odd extra bit of space at the bottom of my logo inside `nav-cont`, and I can't work out where it's coming from.

It looks like this:

What it really looks like:

[image: What it really looks like]

HTML code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav-holder">
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont"><img src="images/placeholder-logo.jpg"/></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont">Listings</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont">Services</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont">About</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont">Blog</div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item">
            <div class="nav-cont">Contact</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#nav-holder {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.nav-cont {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Attempted fixes:

- Checked to see if there was a margin or padding set for images or for `div`s in general.
- Looked for information in the most similar solved problem on StackOverflow ("CSS flexbox vertically/horizontally center image WITHOUT explicitely defining parent height")
- Went through a couple of flexbox tutorials to see if there were any similar issues described, including "Solved by Flexbox" on GitHub and "Dive into Flexbox" by Greg Smith

Comment: I think you are looking for `align-items: stretch` on the child items.

Comment: Tried that already, but it didn't fix the problem.  The items are stretching fine, but the one containing the logo stretches too far.

Comment: Don't forget that inline-level elements get baseline alignment: [**Mystery white space underneath image tag**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Bingo, that had the answer to my question.  I needed to set the image to `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

I have took at look at your code and changed some CSS to try to get the idea of what you want.

```
#nav-holder {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.nav-cont {
    background-color: green;
    width: 70px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Here is a Jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/r3msjtnL/

You had to change the nav-cont div to a pixel and float the text in the center, so it is not unbalanced. Also, I added a padding to make space around your nav.items.

**Update:**

If you do not want your buttons being fixed to a specific pixel, attempt changing the width to a percentage (%) instead !

**If this helped vote up !**

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r3msjtnL/

Comment: Sorry, no go.  First, I don't actually want to force all my items to be the same width--the one with the logo should be able to stretch to fill the logo.  (Which it does fine now.)  But it still doesn't get rid of that 'extra' bit of green on the bottom, even if I remove the padding.  (It looks like it does in the JS fiddle because the image isn't there and doesn't stretch out the `<div>` the same way.

Comment: Is there anyway you could link me a URL of your logo, ill play around with it on Jsfiddle.

Comment: @L.S actually @Michael_B provided a solution in the comments to the original.  I just needed to set the image to `display: block`.