# Weird whitespace after img tags

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to get rid of the space (red) between the `<img>` and the `<div>`. This is as minimal as I could get it.

I found on some other, similar threads that the issue is often due to whitespace or newlines in between `inline-box` elements. This is not the case here.

How to get rid of the space?

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
}

#container {
  background-color: #F00;
}

img {
  background-color: #AFA;
  width: 5em;
  height: 4em;
}

#child {
  background-color: #AAF;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="404"><div id="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change the `display` of the `img` element to `block`, or add `vertical-align: top` to the `img` element.

Comment: Keep in mind that images are, by default, inline-level elements, which receive baseline alignment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Comment: @JoshCrozier That's a lot easier than I thought! Why is that though?

Comment: JeroenBollen - See the answer that @Michael_B wrote and linked to.

Comment: @Michael_B Oh, so that's why! Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` or `display: block;` to your `img{}` -rules.