# CSS - div extend height to match sibling

Tags: html, css

The code below gives this result:

[image]

Which is very close to the result I want except three facts:

1. Why is there a very odd grey area at the bottom of the picture?
2. How can I make the orange div extend to the bottom of the picture? I tried `height: 100%` but it didn't work...
3. How can I also give a 10 pixels space between the div of the text and the picture?

Desired result:

[image]

```css
div.div1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.div2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  float: right;
}

div.div3 {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://splendidwillow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Allium-Purple-garlic-flowers-200x200.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    Text about flowers
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assume your desired result as table. You can create same using div's with display:table and two display:table-cell.

Comment: The thing here is that the `parent div` the yellow part does not have a fixed height which kinda not allow the child to expand unless you give it the height of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div.div1 {
  display: flex;            /* 1 */
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.div2 {
  order: 1;                 /* 2 */
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div.div3 {
  flex: 1;                  /* 3 */
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* height: 100%  */       /* 4 */
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

img {
  vertical-align: bottom;   /* 5 */
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <img src="http://splendidwillow.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Allium-Purple-garlic-flowers-200x200.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    Text about flowers
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. Establish flex container. By default, children will line-up in a row (`flex-direction: row`) with equal height (`align-items: stretch`).
2. Make image appear last in visual display (default `order` value for all flex items is `0`)
3. Make orange box consume all available space in the row.
4. Remove defined heights on flex items. They will override `align-items` equal height feature.
5. [Mystery white space underneath image tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

1. Surely `img`'s `margin-bottom`, set it to 0.
2. [Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) surely is your friend here.
3. Same as **1**, but with `margin-left` in `img` and `margin-right` in `.div2`, both of 5.