# How to make row's column content height to fit sibling column height if the content is populated by a for loop?

Tags: html, css, angular

The following threads were not helping with my situation:

[How to make bootstrap column height to 100% row height? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213171/how-to-make-bootstrap-column-height-to-100-row-height)

[CSS - div extend height to match sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701374/css-div-extend-height-to-match-sibling)

[Make a div fill the height of the remaining screen space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space?rq=1)

I am populating the column's content by a for loop and I don't know the height for the column with the highest content.

I want to make the sibling columns to automatically fit to the highest column height and within the column it has a few rows of data where I would want them to have equal height as well when they are being stretched to fit the highest column.

How can I achieve this?

Here's a sample picture for my current situation:

[image: description]

Essentially, I want to achieve the following:

[image: despcription2]

Here's my `component.html`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-4">
            <div *ngFor="let element1 of level1" style="min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
                {{element1}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div *ngFor="let element2 of level2" style="min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
                {{element2}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div *ngFor="let element3 of level3" style="min-height: 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
                {{element3}}
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and my `componenet.ts` where I'm instantiating the string array to populate my column:

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  level1: string[] = ["1A"];
  level2: string[] = ["2A", "2B", "2C"];
  level3: string[] = ["3A", "3B", "3C", "3D", "3E"];
}
```

I tried setting `max-height: fit-content` to my row and `height: 100%` to my content `<div>` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using flexbox, by adding the following css:

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

`flex-grow` will make sure the elements will fill up the remaining heights.
so add this to all the `div` elements, and they will behave as you want them to