# Small Space in CSS-Grid Cell

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a simple blog layout using CSS Grid. The code is adding a 6px space at the bottom of the div holding the leading image in the post. I cannot eliminate this gap unless I explicitly size the row, which breaks the responsiveness of the site. The image file in the div is sized at 1140x760px.

[image]

CSS:

```
.post {
  display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "hero hero"
      "article sidebar";
    grid-template-columns: 4fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.post > div > img {
  width: 100%;
}

#hero {
  grid-area: hero;
}

#article {
  grid-area: article;
}

#sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="post">
  <div id="hero">
    <img src="/images/{{ page.hero }}.jpg">
  </div>
  <div id="article">
    <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
    {{ page.content }}
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    {% include sidebar.html %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align: top` to your `img` elements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Comment: Try put a **display: block** on the **img** tag, this is a classic case with an img tag that create a space with **display: inline**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put a `display: block` on the **img** tag, this is a classic case with an img tag that create a space with `display: inline`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is coming from your **[`grid-gap: 5px;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap)** in `.post`, which denotes how much space there should be between each child of `.post`. Simply remove this and your elements will be flush up against each other.

Naturally, this will remove *all* of the gaps from the layout. If you only want horizontal gaps, you can use **[`grid-column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-gap)**, and if you only want vertical gaps, you can use **[`grid-row-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-gap)**. If you only want a gap in a specific place, you can use [**`margin`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) instead.

Comment: I think he may be referring to the bottom gap inside the dashed border.

Comment: Oh! I didn't even spot that at first. In that case, you may indeed be looking for `vertical-align: top`. If not, simply ensure that your `<img>` tags actually take up the full height of their container with `height: 100%` :)