# Problems with underlining

Tags: html

I am designing a very basic webpage, with basic HTML and CSS.
So, I have designated a subpage for my "blog":jx-s-potato.glitch.me

On the page,by writing the following code:

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title1"><u>The Blog</u></h1>
</body>
```

I expected "The Blog" to show up with an underline.However, only "The Blo" got underlined. I thought that this was a problem with my browser so I used Safari to view it.The problem remained.

Is there something wrong about my code? Please help!

Comment: I guess that is due to the `descenders`. That means the lower part of `g` is below the `baseline`. Since some `updates` underlines are breaked at `descenders`. To remain legibility.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/7148391

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly! I tried all the solutions suggested by that page which you suggested @ZohirSalak CeNa, but the problem still remained.

Comment: I guess the link by @ZohirSalakCeNa was more to picture the problem. There is no programming solution. Look at Google headlines to see how it works!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use some styling and mimic the underline.

I used Pseudo-element `after` here, but you can do whatever you like.

```css
u{
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
}
u:after{
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height:2px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:4px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title1"><u>The Blog</u></h1>
```