# Image is scaled differently depending on browser if display flex property is used

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following simple `HTML` and `CSS`:

```css
.profile {
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: green;
}

.profile_picture {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.profile_picture img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.profile_discription {
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  
  <div class="profile_picture">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150">
  </div>
   
  <div class="profile_description">
  <p> Description goes here. </p>
  </div>
   
<div>
```

The code displays a website with a profile consisting of a picture and a description. 
You can also find the code in the `jsfiddle` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/WebTiger/pL5adrfs/7/).

All this works fine so far.

---

However, the problem is that once I us the `display: flex;` property in the class `.profile` the picture is shown in different sizes depending if I use Edge, Firefox or Chrome.

Do you have any idea how I can avoid the different sizes of the picture and still be able to use the `display:flex;` property?

Comment: I'm seeing an identical rendering across Edge, Chrome and FF (latest versions).

Comment: Strange. I downloaded Chrome today and I have the latest version of FF so not sure what is different on my site.

Comment: The issue only happens if I use the code in a full screen of the website. Just running the code here in stackoverflow does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just ran the code on full-screen on all 3 browsers. No difference.

Comment: BTW, if you're interested in removing that gap underneath the image, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31444891/3597276

Comment: Thanks for the additional help. However, the strange thing is that this gap on my site only exists on the snipped in stackoverflow and jsfiddle. When I load the same code on full-screen there is no gap. How is it on your site?

Comment: Maybe on your site there is additional code that applies.