# Centering flex children without extra space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

MWE:
https://jsfiddle.net/zjgc9dfx/

Suppose I've got this layout:

```
<div class="slider">
  <span>button here</span>
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/1000" alt="Bacn">
    </div>
  <span>button here</span>
</div>
```

The `slider` is a flex container. The two buttons are `inline-block`, and I want the `slide img` to be limited to the viewport's height without extra space.

How can I achieve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span>asd</span>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/1000" alt="Bacn">
  </div>
  <span>asd</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will work:

```css
.slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.slider>span {
  flex-shrink: 0;    /* disables shrinking feature */
}

.slider>.slide {
  flex: 1;          /* consume all free space */
  height: 100%;
}

.slider .slide img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  vertical-align: bottom;    /* https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276 */
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <span>button here</span>
  <div class="slide">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/1000/1000" alt="Bacn">
  </div>
  <span>button here</span>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zjgc9dfx/2/)

Comment: Close, but it doesn't respect the slide's aspect ratio (`object-fit: cover` crops the image). Fix the `.slide` to 80% height, then apply only `max-height` and `vertical-align` to the `img` and you'll reproduce my issue.