# Non-direct subchildren of a flex container seem vertically misaligned. Why?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have three (yellow framed) labels: A, B, and C.

I want A to be left-aligned and B and C to be right aligned. As I don't want the frame of A to grow until reaching B, I set A's `display: inline`. This almost seems to work, but for some reason A is misbehaving: it shows up vertically misaligned. This seems to originate from this being the only `p` element that is not a direct subchild of the flex container. But why does this happen?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
}

.node {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="background: red;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
    <p class="node" style="display: inline;">A</p>
  </div>
  <p class="node">B</p>
  <p class="node">C</p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `display: inline` use `display: inline-block` ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnge96j5/)). The gap you're seeing underneath "A" is the [space for descenders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276).

Comment: @Michael_B it's not really the descender. It's due to the fact that padding-top/bottom applied to inline element doesn't affect the layout so his top padding is overflowing from the top instead of pushing the element to the bottom like with B, C

Comment: @TemaniAfif, good point. That manages to remove most of the gap. But even after the padding issue is resolved, there is still descender space. Switching to `inline-block` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only children (direct descendants) of `flex` elements have properties of `flex-item`s.

Here you are:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.node {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
}

.node:first-child {margin-right:auto}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="background: red;">
  <p class="node">A</p>
  <p class="node">B</p>
  <p class="node">C</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh. Seems to work and it's simpler. But I still have the same question: what was setting the whole thing off before?

Comment: @devouredelysium, when you wrapped `p` into `div`, `div` became a `flex-item` with the corresponding properties. The `p` because of `display:inline` became a regular inline element and was not stretched anymore.

Comment: @devouredelysium, because it expands right margin to all available space and pushes  A to the left.

Comment: Just a quick point on your wording: "direct children" is redundant. All children are direct descendants.

Comment: @Michael_B, you're absolutely right, but I had to emphasize it =)) fixed.