# why is there an extra gap in this div? how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

This is a section from a practice project, where there's some extra space at the bottom of the element.

[image]

I've checked the code but I can't figure where I've gone wrong. Could someone help find the error?

How do i remove the gap?

````css
/*  DESSERT OF THE DAY  */

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

.image-2 {
  background-image: url(_images/cupcake.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 50vw;
}

.section-2 {
  width: 50vw;
}

.section-2 h3 {
  margin: 5% 35%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.section-2 h1 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.section-2 p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.cherry {
  height: 3%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

```
````

```html
<!---DESERT OF THE DAY-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-2"></div>
  <div class="section-2">
    <h3>Dessert of the Day:</h3>
    <h1>Cherry butterscotch<br>cupcake</h1>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quibusdam corporis ex aut, quae nulla possimus voluptas rerum at a quaerat corrupti ratione et eveniet repellendus illum nobis omnis fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Laboriosam repellat velit quas doloremque magnam consectetur molestias eaque expedita? Laudantium quidem, officia consectetur officiis non at quam itaque sequi nostrum alias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus
      natus voluptas perferendis! Facere nihil suscipit commodi omnis tempore, provident aliquid nostrum officia excepturi maxime minus veritatis quae mollitia facilis aut.</p>
    <img src="_images/cherry.jpeg" class="cherry">
  </div>
</div>
<!--CUSTOMER REVIEWS-->
<div class="container-2">
  <h1>What our customers say</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: _"extra space at the bottom of the element."_ Which element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445364/3597276

Comment: Another thing: when i make the browser size something like, 50%, the image height takes up the whole space and the gap isn't there anymore - i'm a beginner so i have no clue what's happening

Comment: the container div

Comment: Your mean is the same gap between .container and .container2? so set `margin-bottom: -20px;` to .container!

Comment: I tried that, but the gap isn't going @ArmanEbrahimi

Comment: Excuse me. Of course, I said -20px based on the image not loaded! can try `margin-bottom: -400px;` for `.container`. I examined that in the snippet code.

Comment: okay trying that out

Comment: nope, not working :/

Comment: See my answer. is it how? Of course, this makes a gap after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````css
/*  DESSERT OF THE DAY  */

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-bottom: -400px;
}
.image-2 {
  background-image: url(_images/cupcake.jpeg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 50vw;
}

.section-2 {
  width: 50vw;
}

.section-2 h3 {
  margin: 5% 35%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.section-2 h1 {
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
  font-size: 4em;
}

.section-2 p {
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

.cherry {
  height: 3%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 2vh;
}

```
````

```html
<!---DESERT OF THE DAY-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-2"></div>
  <div class="section-2">
    <h3>Dessert of the Day:</h3>
    <h1>Cherry butterscotch<br>cupcake</h1>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint quibusdam corporis ex aut, quae nulla possimus voluptas rerum at a quaerat corrupti ratione et eveniet repellendus illum nobis omnis fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit. Laboriosam repellat velit quas doloremque magnam consectetur molestias eaque expedita? Laudantium quidem, officia consectetur officiis non at quam itaque sequi nostrum alias. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus
      natus voluptas perferendis! Facere nihil suscipit commodi omnis tempore, provident aliquid nostrum officia excepturi maxime minus veritatis quae mollitia facilis aut.</p>
    <img src="https://s4.uupload.ir/files/1-6-5_ssnb.jpg" class="cherry">
  </div>
</div>
<!--CUSTOMER REVIEWS-->
<div class="container-2">
  <h1>What our customers say</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: trying this out too

Comment: this is doing something weird....

Comment: the gap isn't going

Comment: although the customer review h1 tag went

Comment: I edited my answer Do you want "h1 customer review" to go to the top of the page?

Comment: In this case, set `.container-2{position: absolute;top: 0;left: 10px;}` for `.container-2`